# Spark lost values during groupby

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a strange behaviour in pyspark and I cant figure out which is the problem.

I have a DataFrame of triplets that represents the edges of a graph, e.g. (r1, r2, 1.0), (r1, r3, 4.0), (r2, r4, 0.5) and so on.

For each node of the graph I want to compute its maximum associated weight (i.e. to its connected edges), then by using a formula I want to discard some edges.

This is the code:

```
    over_t = edges.filter("weight >= 0.5")
    over_t.cache()
    over_t.count()

    r1_max_w = sc.broadcast(over_t.groupby('p1').max('weight').rdd.collectAsMap())
    r2_max_w = sc.broadcast(over_t.groupby('p2').max('weight').rdd.collectAsMap())

    def do_pruning(r1, r2, weight):
        threshold = 0.35 * (r1_max_w.value[r1] + r2_max_w.value[r2])
        return weight >= threshold

    pruning_udf = f.udf(do_pruning, BooleanType())

    result = over_t \
        .select("r1", "r2", "weight", pruning_udf("r1", "r2", "weight").alias("keep")) \
        .where("keep") \
        .select("p1", "p2", "weight")
```

The problem is that sometimes I got the error that a key is not present in the broadcasted map. If I run the code many time the errors sometimes disappear, as if it is not deterministic.

How this could be possible?

When I create the map I perform a groupby by the record column, so all the records **must be** in there.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you please illustrate the error with sample data? eg entry data, results obtained and expected output

Comment: Hi,
I think that the error is caused by the lazy evaluation of Spark, but I do not really understand why.

I tried to reproduce the error [here](https://github.com/Gaglia88/misc/blob/master/Error%20test.ipynb) but it works correctly.

This is the [notebook](https://github.com/Gaglia88/misc/blob/master/Generalized%20Supervised%20Meta-blocking.ipynb) in which I obtain the error. I noticed that if I force the computation of the "edge" dataframe (by adding the two commented lines) the error disappears.

Comment: You should update the initial post and replace links with values, as the former will last whereas the links could be deleted, and the objective is to make the topic stay consistent